# Accessing exception from different exception strategy types in Mule

Tags: mule

When using catch-exception-strategy in mule, I can access the exception via MEL using `#[exception]`, but this doesn't work for default-exception-strategy. Instead I have to use `#[payload.getException()]`. Is this the correct behavior? And why is this?

Comment: The behaviour discrepancy looks like a bug IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Hi one solution is you can set your catch exception strategy as default exception strategy defined it globally. This is strange actually but you can go ahead with this solution.